# Why are private members __numerator and __denominator accessible, in particular, can be printed, in the following Python code?

Tags: python, class, object

```
class Fraction(object):
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        """Inits Fraction with values numerator and denominator."""
        self.__numerator = numerator
        if(denominator==0):
            raise ValueError('Zero as denominator')
        else:
            self.__denominator = denominator
    def getNumerator (self):
        """*Returns the numerator of a Fraction."""
        return self.__numerator
    def getDenominator (self):
        """Returns the denominator of a Fraction."""
        return self.__denominator
    def setNumerator (self, value):
        """Sets the numerator of a Fraction to the provided value.”"""
        self.__numerator = value
    def setDenominator (self, value):
        """Sets the denominator of a Fraction to the provided value.
        Raises a ValueError exception if a value of zero provided.
        """
        if value == 0:
            raise ValueError('Divide by Zero Error')
        self.__denominator = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__numerator)+'/'+str(self.__denominator)
    def __neg__ (self):
        """Returns a new Fraction equal to the negation of self."""
        return Fraction(-self._numerator, self.__denominator)
    def __add__ (self, qwerty):
        """Returns a new reduced Fraction equal to self + rfraction."""
        numer = self.__numerator * qwerty.getDenominator() + \
        qwerty.getNumerator() * self.__denominator
        denom = self.__denominator * qwerty.getDenominator ()
        resultFrac = Fraction(numer, denom)
        return resultFrac


frac3=Fraction(2,3)
frac3.__numerator=5
print(frac3)
frac3.__denominator=0
print(frac3)

print(frac3.__numerator, frac3.__denominator)
```

```
OUTPUT :

  2/3  
  2/3  
  5 0
```

I am new to Python and started reading about objects and classes. In the first two lines of the output, the fact that members __numerator, __denominator are private was reflected, the assignments 'frac3.__numerator=5' and 'frac3.__denominator=0' had no effect, albeit strange that there was no error generated. In the third line it seems that both private instance variables were printed without errors, why is that?

Comment: Python doesn't really have a concept of private

Comment: Python doesn't have access controls. "private" is only a naming convention

Comment: They can only be printed because you assigned to them, though - the actual internal versions get _name mangled_.